# VS2013 ASP.NET MVC Single Page Application Template Auto Redirection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

The default SPA template in ASP.NET, in Visual Studio 2013 provides us with a default web site template. However, this template does not allow to see /Home/Index page and automatically redirects to /Account/Login. Now, I do want to use this nice feature, but not on my home page.

I have tried the following:

1. commenting out the Authorize attribute
2. adding AllowAnonymous, OverrideAuthentication etc. one by one.

```
//[Authorize]
[AllowAnonymous]
[OverrideAuthentication]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [OverrideAuthentication]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

But it still redirects me to

> http://example.com:49838/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FAuthorize%3Fclient_id%3Dweb%26response_type%3Dtoken%26state%3D

whenever I go to

> http://example.com:49838/Home/Index

How can I prevent that?

Comment: I found a way but I'm pretty sure this is not the right way, comment this line in app.viewmodel.js :

    window.location = "/Account/Authorize?client_id=web&response_type=token&state=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.hash);

If anyone has a better solution, I would really to know as well !

Answer (score 4):

First, remove the Authorize attribute from the Home controller

```
//[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

Then in /Views/Home/Index.cshtml remove the SPA logic (I've commented it out):

```
@section SPAViews {
    @Html.Partial("_Home")
}
@section Scripts{
    @*
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app")
    *@
}
```

Basically what you are doing is making the Home page a regular old MVC page, which is what I'm guessing you want to do.

Then you can link off to a new page which will host your SPA application (and require the user to be signed in).

Answer (score 3):

In your controller:

```
//[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

In your knockout view model

```
app.addViewModel({
    name: "Home",
    bindingMemberName: "home",
    factory: HomeViewModel,
    // add this line only if you require authorization, remove or set to false in your home view model
    authorize: true 
});
```

And finally in your app view model:

```
self[options.bindingMemberName] = ko.computed(function () {
    if (options.authorize && !dataModel.getAccessToken()) {
        ...
    }
    return self.Views[options.name];
});
```

Comment: Definitely forgot to check the Knockout Bundle. Thanks for the answer!