# Endless redirect to ~/Account/Login MVC 5.2.3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, owin

I have similiar problem with [Endless redirect to the login page using the site template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064668/asp-net-mvc-5-endless-redirect-to-the-login-page-using-the-site-template/26072693)
but the resolution did not work for me as on solution properties, Windows auth already disabled and Anonymous already enabled.

in web.config, I already declared

`authentication mode="None"`
(i have tried `authentication mode="Forms"`> also).

but stil, every request get redirected to endless loop 
`http://[domain]/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FRetur...`

this issue appear on live hosting but not on my local iis express server

another similiar issue [Serious need for help](https://what.thedailywtf.com/topic/15201/serious-need-for-help-windows-authentication-in-webconfig-breaks-site), unfortunately it did not get answer

Comment: Do you have any custom filters doing redirects? Made sure you have [AllowAnonymous] filter on your login action? This is a difficult issue to help with because mostly it'll just be guesses at what the problem could be. But roughly, you'll need to find where it's redirecting to login and put in some code that checks the `Request context`, and if it's trying to navigate to the same action it's already navigating to, then don't let it redirect. I've seen people make this mistake in custom filters often though. - but all of this is useless if you have something like url rewriting in IIS

Comment: Oh I just read you're only having the issue in IIS. Whoops.

Answer (score -1):

@Topher yes with IIS, 
I have contacted our hosting provider regarding the issue then adding following setting (inside system.webServer)

```
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication password="[ (iis generated password) ]" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
```

what works for me.
So the short answer is: `Contact Him`

regards